# How to restart javascript function using jquery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I have a timer that executes via php/html like this

```
// timer
print "<script>countdown();</script>";
```

However I have a jquery warning dialog that looks like this, I would like for the javascript function to restart after they click the close button

```
    // Create timeout warning dialog
    $('body').append('<div title="Timeout"</div>');
    $('#sessionTimeout-dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 600,
        modal: true,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        open: function(event, ui) { $(".dialog").hide(); },
        buttons: {
            // Button two - closes dialog and makes call to keep-alive URL
            "Continue Session": function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                clearTime();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: o.keepAliveUrl
                });


                countdown(); //I call the javascript function in hopes of making it go again
            }
        }
    });
```

However I cant seem to make the timer actually restart once the button is click to continue. here is my timer code, what I'am I doing wrong? I call the javascript function after the button is closed but nothing happens it just goes to a negative number

```
      // set minutes
var mins = 2;

// calculate the seconds (don't change this! unless time progresses at a different speed for you...)
var secs = mins * 60;   

function countdown() {
    setTimeout('Decrement()',1000);
}

function Decrement() {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        minutes = document.getElementById("minutes");
        seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
    // if less than a minute remaining
    if (seconds < 59) {
        seconds.value = secs;
    } else {
        minutes.value = getminutes();
        seconds.value = getseconds();
    }
        secs--;
        setTimeout('Decrement()',1000);
    }
}

function getminutes() {
    // minutes is seconds divided by 60, rounded down
    mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
    return mins;
}

function getseconds() {
    // take mins remaining (as seconds) away from total seconds remaining
    return secs-Math.round(mins *60);
}
```

Comment: What is `controlRedirTimer`?

Comment: @Blender it was an attempt at a function, I deleted it since it wasnt relevent anymore, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your countdown function doesn't reset the timer, but only starts the decrement loop.

Add something like

```
function resetCountdown()
{
    secs = mins * 2;
}
```

and call this function when the dialog is closed to reset the countdown. Do NOT call countdown() again as this will create another timer in addition to the already running one.

Also there is an error in your code:

```
if (seconds < 59) {
    seconds.value = secs;
} else {
    minutes.value = getminutes();
    seconds.value = getseconds();
}
```

should be

```
if (secs < 59) {
    minutes.value = 0;
    seconds.value = secs;
} else {
    minutes.value = getminutes();
    seconds.value = getseconds();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure this is what you want, but:

I like to restart certain timers when the window regains focus(from the dialog).  Below is an example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            g = {};
            g.timer = false;
            g.count = false;
            g.waittime = 3; //seconds for timer.
            g.timeleft = (g.waittime * 100) - 10;
            checktimer = function(){
                if(g.timer === false){
                    g.timer = setTimeout(function(){
                        g.timer = false;
                        g.timeleft = g.waittime * 100;
                        alert("Hi!");
                    },g.waittime * 1000);
                }
                if(g.count === false){
                    g.count = setInterval(function(){
                        g.timeleft-=10;
                        document.getElementById("disp").innerText =(g.timeleft/100).toString().match(/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?/);
                    },100);
                }
            }
            window.onfocus = function() {
                checktimer();
            };

        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="checktimer();">
        <div>Time Left: <span id="disp">0</span> Seconds.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```